# PHP While loop for Select Query

Tags: php, while-loop

Can anyone explain me how to get the final value assigned to variable after completing executing while loop?

In my below code I wanted to echo the response out of while loop after fetching all the values from the rows.

Because if I put echo out of while loop it only shows 1st record.

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($array)) {
    $response = $row['0']->load();
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: You will get the last rows value into the `$response`, **Cause:** Every time  the loop executes will assign value into the variable. But as you echo it you can see all the values as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the last rows value into the `$response`.

**Cause:** Every time the loop executes will assign value into the variable. But as you echo it you can see all the values as output.

> So what you really need to do is storing the values in an array...

```
$response = array();
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($array)) {
      $response[] = $row['0']->load();
}

print_r($response);
```

If you need further information about this , just let me know.

Comment: you can consider to use [oci_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php) instead `oci_fetch_array` to not need to do `while` loop

Answer (score 2):

Since you are doing `variable assignment` and `echo` inside `while` loop, it will not serve your purpose.

You have to do it like below:-

```
$response = array(); // create an array
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($array)) {
      $response[] = $row['0']->load(); // assign each value to array
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($response);// print the array
```

Note:- this array will have all the values now. You can manipulate it in your desired way.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$response = [];
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($array)) {
  $response[] = $row['0']->load();
}

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: This is returning only 1st row.

Comment: You have added `$row['0']`. It will loop till the end and then will return the row's first value cause key is 0

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($array)) {
   $response = $row['0']->load();
}
echo $response;
```

Comment: This is returning only 1st row.

Comment: what is echoing the echo inside the loop? and what should be echoign? copy and paste it